# Do we have any Hadith which chains going from Imam Jaffar or Imam Baqir to Hazrat Ali in the Sunni Hadith collections?

Tags: hadith, shia-sunni, ali, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith, isnad

I recently came across the following Hadith and was wondering if anyone has a collection of Hadith from Imam Jaffar or Imam Baqir to Hazrat Ali in the Sunni Hadith collections.  Would be very interesting to see that chain of isnad.

***Imam ‘Abdur Razzaq (rahimahullah) has recorded this Hadith on the authority of Muhammad Al Baqir (rahimahullah); the great-grandson of Sayyiduna ‘Ali ibn Abi Talib (radiyallahu ‘anhu).
Muhammad ibn ‘Ali ibn Husayn (rahimahullah) reported that Rasulullah (sallallahu ‘alayhi wa sallam) said: “It is ill-mannered/discourteous that I am mentioned in the presence of an individual and he does not invoke blessings [salutations/durud] upon me.”
(Musannaf ‘Abdur Razzaq, Hadith: 3121)

‘Allamah Sakhawi (rahimahullah) has declared the narrators reliable (thiqat).
(Al Qawlul Badi’, pg. 311. Also see: Nataijul Afkar, vol. 4 pg. 36)***

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about this site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note since imam Malik was a student of imam Ja'afar as-Sadiq he has quoted a handful of narrations on his authorithy in his al-Muwatta'. A meeting of abu Hanifa and Ja'afar as-Sadiq however is widely discussed and later scholars strongly doubt narratives of such a meeting.

Comment: Wasalaam.  JazakAllah khair for the information. I'll try and go through the Muwatta to find such narrations by Imam Jaffar.